# How is a positive rational number defined by making use of the order present in $\mathbb Z$? (proof writing)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm looking for help on the proof below. I believe that my logic is sound, but I'm wondering if there is a way to condense this down (it just seems like a long proof). Any help would be welcome!

*Definition:* Assume that $S$ is a field. Then $S$ is an ordered field if $S$ can be partitioned into three disjoint sets: $P$, $-P={-x|x \text{ is in }P}$ and ${0}$, such that if $x,y \in P$, then $x+y \in P$ and $x \cdot y \in P$.

*Theorem:* Let S be an ordered field. For any $x, y \in S$, exactly one of the following holds:
$$x=y, x>y, \text{or } y>x\text{.}$$

**Show how:** a positive rational number can be defined by making use of the order present in $\mathbb Z$.

**Proof:** By definition, rational numbers can be expressed by $\frac ab$ with integers $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ and $b \neq0$.

In this case, since all integers can be partitioned into positive integers ($P$), negative integers ($-P$), and $0$, we have 6 cases to analyze.

*Case 1:* $a>0$, $b>0$.

Because $b>0$ (by a previous result), $\frac 1b>0$. Thus $(a-0)\in P$, $(b-0)\in P$, and $(\frac 1b-0)\in P$.

Since we know that $x,y \in P \Rightarrow x\cdot y \in P$, consider 
$$(a-0)\cdot (\frac 1b -0)=a \cdot \frac1b-0\cdot a- 0\cdot \frac 1b +0= \frac ab$$
Therefore, $\frac ab -0 \in P$, meaning $\frac ab >0$.

*Case 2:* $a>0$, $b<0$.

As above, because $b<0$ (by a previous result), $\frac 1b<0$, which implies $0-\frac 1b \in P$. Thus (as above) $(a-0)\cdot (0-\frac 1b) \in P$, so

$$(a-0)\cdot (0-\frac 1b)= a\cdot 0 - a \cdot \frac1b- 0\cdot \frac 1b +0= \frac {-a}b$$

Therefore $\frac ab \in -P$, so $\frac ab<0$.

*Case 3:* $a<0$, $b>0$.

Can be proved using the same logic as (Case 2).

*Case 4:* $a<0$, $b<0$.

As before, $b<0 \Rightarrow \frac 1b<0$. So $(0-a), (0- \frac 1b)\in P$. As before, this implies that $(0-a)\cdot (0-\frac 1b)\in P$. So
$$(0-a)\cdot (0-\frac 1b)=(-a)\cdot (-\frac 1b)=\frac ab$$

Therefore, $\frac ab \in P$ and $\frac ab>0$.

*Cases 5 & 6:* $a=0$, $b>0$ & $a=0$, $b<0$.

As shown before, $0\cdot a=0$, so in both cases $a\cdot \frac 1b=0$.

Therefore, $a=0 \Rightarrow \frac ab=0$.

By all of the cases above, we can conclude that $\frac ab$ will be a positive rational number when $a>0$ and $b>0$ or when $a<0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: Can you write down the statement you are trying to prove?  This isn't clear in your post.  (Edit it into your question.)

Comment: I think what you are actually trying to do is to *define* an order on the rationals, given that the integers are ordered. Then you would want to prove that the order so defined is indeed an order.

Comment: Um... *what* are you trying to prove?

Comment: I made some edits in an attempt to clarify what I'm trying to show. I could be off base, but I *believe* that I am trying to use the fact that $\mathbb Z$ is an ordered field in order to define positive rational numbers. Said another way (my interpretation), what conditions do the two integers used to form a rational number need to meet in order for it to be positive?

Comment: Didn't read all of your post but a rational number is an *equivalence class* of expressions $\frac{a}{b}$, not the expressions themselves. $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ are representatives of the same rational. Don't know whether that affects the rest of your post.

Comment: @BernardW how would I start to go about that? I feel like I'm limited by how I'm (mis)understanding the question.